# Improving Lightning Performance - What does SFDC consider "Salesforce organization configuration issues"?

Tags: lightning, bestpractice, performance

Per the following SFDC [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316034&type=1&mode=1), Salesforce indicates four main reasons for Lightning Performance Issues and page load time:

1. Geographical
2. Device
3. Browser
4. **Salesforce organization configuration issues**

Items 1-3 above are generally out of a technical architect/admin's ability to control. However I was wondering if there was more information as to guidelines/best practices around #4 - Salesforce organization configuration issues. Our org seems incredibly slow within LXE. The article lists a few suggestions, which we will are currently improving.

I imagine cleaning up the following would be good examples of best practices: Data cleanup, # of fields on a layout, triggers and automation, callouts, queries, data schema changes, ect.

However I was wondering if anyone has any other "easy wins" or additional best practices that have greatly improved your performance when migrating users to Lightning Experience?

Apologies in advance if this is too vague, but I thought this might be a good chance to help generate discussion on best practices and see what other people are doing. I did find some of the suggestions here very helpful and would welcome any additional tips:
https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/05/22/optimize-your-lightning-page-layout/

Answer (score 0):

You can run the [Salesforce Optimizer report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=optimizer_kick_off.htm&type=5) that gives you information on how to "improve your implementation".

> Salesforce creates a personalized PDF report with advice and
>   recommendations about how you can improve your implementation.
>   Consider running Salesforce Optimizer as part of your monthly
>   maintenance, before installing a new app, before each Salesforce
>   release, or at least once a quarter. You can run the report as often
>   as you want.

Go to Setup --> Optimizer --> Click on *Create PDF*

You should receive an email with a link to the created PDF (which will simply be a file in your org).

It gives you recommendations and some examples are:

- Object layouts with too many fields
- Too many lightning/aura components on Lightning pages
- Objects with too many custom fields
- Unassigned user roles
- Objects with too many workflows
- Too many validation rules on an object

There's many others. Some advice is useful, some may not be as useful or you may not be able to take action on. It's a decent starting point for getting info quick on how your implementation is and starting the conversation though.

Answer (score 0):

Although I had tried including most of the doable facts to improve page performance in the blog you shared:- https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/05/22/optimize-your-lightning-page-layout/, Here are Few more facts:-

For the organisation moved up from classic completely, It is easy to control things. For example, they can easily remove a field from the detail page layout and show it somewhere else in the lightning page like:- Highlight Panel.

But if you are having the classic and lightning both in the org, You cannot take the decision to remove fields from the detail page layout because the highlights panel does not exist there.

I have used these three methods to control the field displayed on the Screen in Lightning:-

1. Using Quick Actions on the Lightning Page to show key fields on the default tab of the page load. Read here if you want an example:- https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/05/30/point-and-click-alternative-to-lightning-data-service/ 
   You can dynamically show the fields based on some condition by creating multiple quick actions of type update a record and show hide the actions using component visibility. Each action will have a different field added on the layout based on the requirement.
2. The [Screen flows](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder/flow-builder-screens) gives you the same ability. You can control the things based on condition using component visibility.
3. [Break Up Your Record Details with Dynamic Forms](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2019/break-up-your-record-details-with-dynamic-forms)

[image]

Now what to do with Related List? You do have control on the related list in Lightning. See how:-

1. Use [Related List - Single](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_related_record_list_single.htm&type=0) component and use component visibility to show and hide it base on condition dynamically. Read these blogs:- [SHOWING A RELATED LIST BASED ON USER PROFILE IN LIGHTNING EXPERIENCE](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/06/20/showing-a-related-list-based-on-user-profile-in-lightning-experience/)
2. Another way is to use the collapsible related list in Lightning using Accordion and Related List - single component. Read more here:- [COLLAPSIBLE RELATED LIST IN LIGHTNING EXPERIENCE](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/03/12/collapsible-related-list-in-lightning-experience/)